# What's the right way to write big-O?

Tags: notation, terminology, asymptotics

I always write $\mathcal{O}(n)$ (`\mathcal{O}(n)`). But I frequently see $O(n)$ (`O(n)`), probably because it's shorter and more convenient to type.

To me, $\mathcal{O}$ makes more sense because it's a set, and sets are frequently written with calligraphic notation (especially sets of sets, such as sets of functions, such as $\mathcal{O}$).

What is the "right" usage? Is there one?

<sub>(Of course, in my $\sf\LaTeX$ documents, I define a `\newcommand\bigO{\mathcal{O}}` for semantic markup, but that's beside the point here.)</sub>

Comment: Both are very common.  There is no "right".

Comment: As long as it doesn't lead to confusion you can use any one of them.

Comment: Do you write little-o in the mathcal font as well?

Comment: Also, it is often used less formally and then not considere a set, in notation like $x\sin x=O(x^2)$ for example, which really makes no sense at all as an equation – though it makes perfect sense if you understand the intent. It has to be read left to right, I guess, thus violating the symmetry of the “$=$” sign. So a possible rough guide could be: Use $O$ when you're informal, $\mathcal{O}$ if you want to be pedantic, and $\mathfrak{O}$ if you want to confuse the heck out of everybody.

Comment: Why does $\mathfrak{O}$ look so much like $\mathfrak{D}$?

Comment: @WChargin To me $\mathfrak{O}$ looks like a mutant version of  Pacman.

Comment: I wanted to share the Unicode versions of the symbols under discussion. Per @HaraldHanche-Olsen’s comment,  is the most pedantically correct;  seems fine; and  is confusing.

Comment: @MathiasBynens  is U+1D4AA MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT CAPITAL O, while  is U+1D512 MATHEMATICAL FRAKTUR CAPITAL O.

Comment: Plain $O$ might be more correct, as it means greek letter Omicron, see [w:Big O notation#Family of Bachmann–Landau notations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations).